# How to display a div which is else part of php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a div "BrowseDiv" which is in else part of php code as shown below. if $url is not exists, it should show the div. Also When check the check box , I'm calling a java script which should display the div.But it is not displaying when onchange checkbox is calling

```
<tr height="20px" >     
    <td style="text-align:center">
    <?php if(file_exists($url)){ ?>
        <a href=<?php echo "documents/".$num."/".$id;?> target="_blank" id="href_doc1">My Doc</a>
         </br>
         <input type="checkbox" id="check_doc1" name="check_doc1"  onchange="CheckedDelete('check_doc1')">Delete My Doc</input>
        <?php } else { ?>
        </br></br>
        <div id="BrowseDiv" ><b></br>Upload Supporting Document</b> </br> 
        <input type="file" name="doc1_upload_onload" id="doc1_upload_onload"> 
        </div> 
     } ?>
    </td>       
</tr>


function CheckedDelete(chk_bx){

    if (document.getElementById(chk_bx).checked == true) {    
      alert(" will be deleted");      
      var href_doc1 = document.getElementById('href_doc1');
      href_doc1.style.display = 'none'; 
      document.getElementById('BrowseDiv').style.display= 'block';      
    } else {
      var Thephoto = document.getElementById('href_doc');
      Thephoto.style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('BrowseDiv').style.display= 'none';   
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `if (document.getElementById(chk_bx).checked == true) {` to `if (document.getElementById(chk_bx).checked) {`

Comment: That is because your BrowseDiv is not present in DOM so your getElementById is throwing an error. Remember that it will only show if file doesn't exist, then your getElementById will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "BrowseDiv" is in else part and hence document.getElementById('BrowseDiv') must be returning NULL.

For this you need to change your logic a bit. Something like this:

```
<td style="text-align:center"><?php if(file_exists($url)){ ?>
<a href=<?php echo "documents/".$num."/".$id;?> target="_blank" id="href_doc1">My Doc</a>
 </br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="check_doc1" name="check_doc1"  onchange="CheckedDelete('check_doc1')">Delete My Doc</input>
<?php   } ?>
</br></br>
<div id="BrowseDiv" style="display: <?php echo (file_exists($url)) ? 'none' : 'block' ?>" ><b></br>Upload Supporting Document</b> </br> 
<input type="file" name="doc1_upload_onload" id="doc1_upload_onload"> 
</div>
```

Comment: shows Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) i

Answer (score 1):

You should do this instead..

```
<tr height="20px" >     
    <td style="text-align:center"><?php if(file_exists($url)){ ?>
    <a href=<?php echo "documents/".$num."/".$id;?> target="_blank" id="href_doc1">My Doc</a>
     </br>
     <input type="checkbox" id="check_doc1" name="check_doc1"  onchange="CheckedDelete('check_doc1')">Delete My Doc</input>
    <?php  } ?>
    </br></br>
    <div id="BrowseDiv" style="display: <?php if(file_exists($url) { echo 'none'; } else { echo 'block'; } ?>"><b></br>Upload Supporting Document</b> </br> 
    <input type="file" name="doc1_upload_onload" id="doc1_upload_onload"> 
    </div>

    </td>       
</tr>
```